# How to efficiently append values to an empty list in Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following code

```
entries = soup.find_all("entry")

master_list_xml = []

for entry in entries:
         accession_num = entry.find("accession-number").text
         print(accession_num)
```

Output is:

```
0001564590-18-019062
0001564590-17-014900
0001193125-16-662209
0001193125-15-272806
```

Now, I want to make a list containing every `accession_num`.

**Question:** What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Kindly mark my solution as your answer and vote up too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are for:

```
entries = soup.find_all("entry")
accession_numbers = [entry.find("accession-number").text for entry in entries]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line `master_list_xml.append(accession_num)` in loop, this will create a List.

```
entries = soup.find_all("entry")

master_list_xml = []

for entry in entries:
         accession_num = entry.find("accession-number").text
         print(accession_num)
         master_list_xml.append(accession_num)
```